# How to check element rectangle by id in Elm?

Tags: javascript, dom, elm

I would like to check position and dimensions of some element (knowing its id) in Elm, without using JS if it's possible. There is package for DOM (http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/latest/DOM), but there are no examples of usage and I am confused with it.

Understanding the Elm nature I would keep this rectangle as something like `Maybe (Int, Int, Int, Int)` in my model and update it probably by some subscription or port.

What is the simplest way to achieve it?

Comment: What can you do without JS? What do you mean checking if there is no JS?

Comment: @ArashKazemi I mean without writing code in js and porting to elm.

Comment: The [debois/elm-dom](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/latest/DOM) package will only give you information about the current event (e.g. you could click a button and find out its dimensions). If you want to get information on an arbitrary DOM element given an ID, you will have to use a port

Comment: @ChadGilbert your comment sounds a lot like an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [debois/elm-dom](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-dom/latest/DOM) package will only give you information about the current event (e.g. you could click a button and find out its dimensions). If you want to get information on an arbitrary DOM element given an ID, you will have to use ports.

This is by design: Any time you need to query the DOM, you are no longer within the purity of Elm; you are querying something that has side effects, and that needs to go through the `Cmd` and `Sub` ports to allow custom javascript. You will need two ports: One to send the request to the DOM and the other to return the results back from javascript to Elm.

```elm
port fetchBoundingClientRect : Id -> Cmd msg

port setBoundingClientRect : (Maybe BoundingClientRect -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

Your javascript could look something like this:

```js
var app = Elm.Main.embed(document.querySelector('main'))
app.ports.fetchBoundingClientRect.subscribe(function(id) {
    var entity = document.getElementById(id);
    app.ports.setBoundingClientRect.send(entity ? entity.getBoundingClientRect() : null);
});
```

This is just a simplified example. You can see it on [ellie-app.com](https://ellie-app.com/WGDLxfRmp7a1). In the real world you would probably want to retain more information, like including the ID of the element on the incoming subscription (in case you query multiple elements and need to keep track of which one is queried).

Comment: Is it possible to have real-time subscription on any DOM change this way? Your solution requires to explicitly request the update. I would like to be informed every time the tracked element is being resized or moved

Comment: Sure, you would just need to implement your javascript event handlers to call the appropriate port.